# Filling an empty dataframe with a single row of zeroes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am transforming a dataframe based on some conditions and sometimes it may return an empty dataframe. i.e columns names are present but no rows.

Is there a way to fill create just 1 row and fill it with a value , say '0'?

I check if the dataframe has no rows with the following syntax:

```
if (dim(df)[1]==0) {
}
```

These are the datatypes of the columns of the dataframe:

```
$ tool_id            : Factor w/ 8 levels 
 $ PHX_lot_id         : chr 
 $ fg_lot_id          : chr 
 $ PHX_stop_time      : Factor w/ 8 levels "2022-05-16T11:38",..: 
 $ fg_stop_time       : Factor w/ 8 levels "2022-05-16T20:38:19",..: 
 $ fg_stop_time_local : Factor w/ 8 levels "2022-05-16T11:38:19",..: 
 $ check              : chr 
 $ PHX_stop_time_TS   : 'POSIXct' num(0) 
 - attr(*, "tzone")= chr ""
 $ fg_stoplocaltime_TS: 'POSIXct' num(0) 
 - attr(*, "tzone")= chr ""
 $ delay              : 'difftime' num 
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "hours"
 $ alarm_flag         : logi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and assign the first row with `df[1, ]` so `df[1, ] <- 0` works.

```
empty_df = na.omit(as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)))
empty_df
 [1] V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

empty_df[1, ] <- 0
empty_df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

Edit:

If you have multiple datatypes, you can assign `NA` instead of `0`.

```
empty_df = na.omit(as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)))
class(empty_df[[1]]) <- "numeric"
class(empty_df[[2]]) <- "character"
empty_df[[3]] <- factor()
class(empty_df[[4]]) <- "POSIXct"
class(empty_df[[5]]) <- "difftime"
class(empty_df[[6]]) <- "logical"
class(empty_df[[7]]) <- "integer"
> str(empty_df)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ V1 : num 
 $ V2 : chr 
 $ V3 : Factor w/ 0 levels: 
 $ V4 : 'POSIXct' logi 
 $ V5 : 'difftime' logi 
 $ V6 : logi 
 $ V7 : int 
 $ V8 : logi 
 $ V9 : logi 
 $ V10: logi
empty_df[1, ] <- NA
empty_df
  V1   V2   V3   V4  V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1 NA <NA> <NA> <NA> NA  NA NA NA NA  NA
```

Comment: I get the error: `'origin' must be supplied`

Comment: Then I am afraid there is not enough information to make progress here. The above code snippet correctly creates an empty `data.frame` and assigns `0` to its first row.

Comment: I think its because of the datatypes of the columns in the dataframe (edited in my original post), some are factors so Im guessing it could not simply assign 0 to it?

Comment: See edited answer.